# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on Spring JDBC

Tags: java

I am using Spring Jdbc to develop a webservice that connects to an Oracle database to fetch some data. I am trying to use `SimpleJdbcCall` to call a database function to fetch the data to the webservice response. But when I try to execute the webservice method I get the following error in the response body

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
    <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/SqlParameterSource;)Ljava/lang/Object;</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ns2:exception xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/" class="java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
          <message>org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/SqlParameterSource;)Ljava/lang/Object;</message>
          <ns2:stackTrace>
```

I haved searched the NoSuchMethodError and found something about different compile and runtime dependencies version . I have check my pom.xml but i cannot find any difference in spring version. Here is my dependencies part from my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring JDBC Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cn.guoyukun.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>args4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version> <!-- <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version> -->
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
</properties>
```

Btw i am deploying on Weblogic 10.3.6

Comment: it is something to do with version spring/spring-jdbc you are using

Comment: Just drawing your attention to this discrepancy: you specify <spring-framework.version>**4.0.6.RELEASE**</spring-framework.version> but you have this in the comments <version>${spring-framework.version}</version> <!-- <version>**4.0.2.RELEASE**</version> --> - probably isn't the cause of your problem though